# Able to get minimum value, count of records in single query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Consider the below schema for tables **User** and **Job**.

**User**

```
id - integer
name - string
job_id - integer
```

**Job**

```
id - integer
job_date - datetime
job_ref - string
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :jobs
end
```

**Job.rb**

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I have tried the below query

```
User
  .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN jobs ON users.job_id = jobs.id AND jobs.job_date > now()::timestamp')
  .select('COUNT(jobs.id) as number_of_jobs, min(jobs.job_date) as next_job')
```

Here I need to take the number of future jobs, job_date and job_ref for next job. I used above query. But i can able to get the number of future jobs by using count and next job date by using min aggregate function. But can't able to get the next job_ref.
In above query can we able to get the job_ref for next job? Is any option available?

Comment: Add your User.rb and Job.rb so that we can clearly understand what kind of relationship you want to have.

Comment: @Yshmarov Added the User.rb and Job.rb.

Comment: What's `job_ref`?

Comment: @SebastianPalma job_ref is job reference which is just like unique id. Ex. 'JOB001'